# Creating Separate Objects with Loops

Tags: java, object, text, arraylist, while-loop

I'm creating a race results program and I need to store all the info from a text file that looks like this:

> ------1   Jackson Bertoli 11  Jasper      15.29-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

As you can see, it contains the place, a first name, a last name, a grade, a school name, and a time.
This information needs to be stored together, so I figured the best way to do this was storing it in an object "runner", and then putting all of those "runner" objects inside an arraylist. The only problem with this is that I can't find how to make a different object name for each object in my while loo (which is going through each line to read the elements from the text file) for each separate runner. Is it even necessary to have a different object name for each object? And if I am allowed to have many separate objects with the same name, how do I distinguish them apart? Here's a bit of the code behind it

```
public void readfile() {
    while (initialresults.hasNext()){

        strplace = initialresults.next();
        dataplace = Integer.parseInt(strplace);

        datafirstname = initialresults.next();

        datalastname = initialresults.next();

        strgrade = initialresults.next();
        datagrade = Integer.parseInt(strgrade);

        dataschool = initialresults.next();

        strorigtime = initialresults.next();
        dataorigtime = Double.parseDouble(strorigtime);

        runner newrunner = new runner(datafirstname,datalastname, datagrade, dataschool, dataorigtime);
        amountofrunners.add(newrunner);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

So you can see I'm reading each element from the text file, and then trying to make a new "runner" object, store those elements from the text file in that object, but then I'm stuck putting the next line's elements in that same object name. How can I create a new object name every time to store those elements in? The only reason I'm using an object is because it seems like the best way to keep data organized for a runner. But if I used an array or a list, wouldn't that get disorganized and difficult to sort through? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions. Classes start with capital letters. And use camel casing for variable And classes.

Comment: And what is not currently working with your code? Also, please make more clear what the input text file looks like. Your description is very unclear.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description. I have made changes to the original post to clarify my problem and the text file details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your loop runs, even though the runner class is being used multiple times, it creates a new (and different) runner object each time the loop iterates (runs through a cycle).

In the line `amountofrunners.add(newrunner);`, Java basically copies the value(s) stored in newrunner and stores it/them seperately. Every object is different in this case, even if it has the same variable name when it's created.

Using an ArrayList actually makes it easier to sort through because you can use indexes, foreach loops, and other features to help manage the objects stored in the ArrayList.

Comment: I already  understand the difference of classes and objects. Where I was unclear was that "apparently" I had made separate objects, since they all had the same name of newrunner, wouldn't I have trouble calling about them for doing functions later on, due to them having the same object name?

Comment: Alright, but when I did this and printed out all my objects from the arraylist they were stored in with the following code `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){  
      System.out.println(amountofrunners.get(i));` I would get an  output that looked something like this `newrunner@32414ja 
newrunner@ij123451 
newrunner@25ia0d12 
newrunner@1r31456 ` For however many runner objects I made. Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I stand corrected. I've updated my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you were trying to do something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public static class Runner{
    int place;
    String firstName, lastName, school;
    double origTime, grade;

    Runner(int place,String firstName,String lastName,double grade,String school,double origTime){
        this.place = place;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.school = school;
        this.origTime = origTime;
    }
}

public static List<Runner> readfile(Scanner in) {
    List<Runner> runners = new ArrayList<Runner>(); 

    while (in.hasNext()){
        runners.add(new Runner(
            in.nextInt(), // place
            in.next(), in.next(), //first, last name
            in.nextDouble(), // grade
            in.next(), // school
            in.nextDouble() // original time
        ));
    }
    return runners;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Runner> runners;

    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt")))) {
        runners = readfile(s);
    }
    // Do something with runners
}
```

Comment: This looks a lot better than what I had before. The only problem I'm having is that I'm reading all of this from a text file which I find using a try catch, and named that file that I was using "initialresults". How can I use this in my readfile constructor instead of the Scanner in. Or could you clarify on what I have to do in order to be able to use the Scanner in as my constructor?

Comment: @CharlesSparkley i added a main class that explains how you would use the readfile function for a file.

Comment: Alright, instead of a buffered reader I'm using ----------------`public void openfile() {
      try{
        initialresults = new Scanner (new File ("C:\\Donalds\\Java\\raceresults.txt"));
        
      }
      catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not find file");
      }
    }` And then my while loop iterates through my initialresults. Also, my main(String[]args) is just in a separate class that is calling upon all of my methods. Could you show how all of this would be done with what I am currently using? Thank you

Comment: Also, there are a lot of errors popping up when using this code.

Comment: @CharlesSparkley Probably because you didn't include dependencies. I've added them to the code. Also, there was a parenthesis that needed to be fixed and class and functions needed to be declared static. Try it now.